# PHP curl_exec times out, from command line I get instant answer

Tags: php, curl, timeout

I'm developing a script where I'm using PHP and cURL to fetch data from a REST web service.

My problem is that curl_exec often times out in the PHP script, but when I try the same request from the command line cURL client I get an instant answer.

It seems like the PHP cURL somehow caches this timeout for some time and then suddenly decides that it's going to fetch the data I need. Multiple reloads produces the same result: timeout. And after a few minutes everything works fine. The command line cURL client has been getting data all the time.

What can be wrong?

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14436877/662732) on how you can get some debug information from cURL.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this curl setting:

`curl_setopt($curl_handler, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);`

Also this setting could be useful, as it forces connection to close after the request is completed:

`curl_setopt($curl_handler, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);`

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately it does not work :( It seems a bit more stable, but the error is still there, just to a lesser degree.

Comment: Also DNS caching could be an issue.Try to disable the DNS caching with the following setting:    curl_setopt($curl_handler, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 0);  <br />Also did you try to use CURLOPT_VERBOSE for debugging? As @fab suggested previously?